# VBA retrieve HTMLBody from Outlook mail

Tags: vba, outlook

First I create an email via Outlook:

```
Sub CreateHTMLMail()
'Creates a new e-mail item and modifies its properties.

Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
Dim objMail As Outlook.MailItem
Set olApp = Outlook.Application
'Create e-mail item
Set objMail = olApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

Dim sHTML_Open              As String
Dim sHTML_Introduction      As String
Dim sHTML_Goodbye           As String
Dim sHTML_Close             As String
Dim sHTML_Process_Date      As String
Dim sHTML_Processor         As String
Dim sHTML_Issuer            As String
Dim sHTML_Details           As String

Dim sHTML_Body              As String

sHTML_Open = "<HTML><BODY>"
sHTML_Introduction = "Hi team,<BR/><BR/>" & _
                        "Data is ready to process. Please find details as below.<BR/>"
sHTML_Process_Date = "<P ID='PROCESSDATE'>28 February 2013</P>"
sHTML_Processor = "<P ID='PROCESSOR'>AKSHAY</ID></P>"
sHTML_Issuer = "<P ID='ISSUER'>DATAGROUP.COM</ID></P>"
sHTML_Details = "<P ID='DETAILS'>" & _
                    "<UL>" & _
                        "<LI>Fimta23456 09:00:00 flor345</LI>" & _
                        "<LI>Fimta23456 09:00:00 flor345</LI>" & _
                    "</UL>" & _
                "</P><BR/>"
sHTML_Goodbye = "Thanks"
sHTML_Close = "</BODY></HTML>"

sHTML_Body = sHTML_Open & sHTML_Introduction & sHTML_Process_Date & sHTML_Processor & sHTML_Issuer & _
          sHTML_Details & sHTML_Goodbye & sHTML_Close

With objMail
   'Set body format to HTML
   .BodyFormat = olFormatHTML
   .To = "Kim Gysen"
   .Subject = "data remit file"
   .HTMLBody = sHTML_Body
   .Display
End With
End Sub
```

Via code, I want to retrieve values based on ID. 
This seemed the cleanest way for me, I don't particulary like the "split" method because it's kind of hard coding; not very dynamic and kinda unreliable.

Unfortunately when I retrieve the HTML body, I cannot retrieve the original HTML, as it is distorted by Outlook:

```
Sub Get_OL()

Dim oFolder                 As MAPIFolder
Dim oItem                   As Variant

Dim sHTML_Body              As String
Dim sHTML_Process_Date      As String
Dim sHTML_Processor         As String
Dim sHTML_Issuer            As String
Dim sHTML_Details           As String

Dim oExcel              As Object
Dim oBook               As Workbook

Set oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set oBook = oExcel.Workbooks.Add


'Access the outlook inbox folder

Set oFolder = GetNamespace("MAPI").PickFolder

'On error resume next usually not to use, but feteching emails may give unexpected errors
On Error Resume Next
For Each oItem In oFolder.Items
    If TypeOf oItem Is Outlook.MailItem Then
        If oItem.Subject Like "*data remit file*" Then
            'Turn off on error resume next asap
            On Error GoTo 0
            sHTML_Body = oItem.HTMLBody
            Debug.Print sHTML_Body

            Exit For
        End If
    End If
Next oItem

End Sub
```

On debug.print, this is what I get (only putting the last line of the Format):

```
</o:shapelayout></xml><![endif]--></head><body lang=EN-GB link=blue vlink=purple><div class=WordSection1><p class=MsoNormal>Hi team,<br><br>Data is ready to process. Please find details as below.<br><br><o:p></o:p></p><p>28 February 2013<o:p></o:p></p><p id=PROCESSOR>AKSHAY<o:p></o:p></p><p id=ISSUER>DATAGROUP.COM<o:p></o:p></p><ul type=disc><li class=MsoNormal style='mso-margin-top-alt:auto;mso-margin-bottom-alt:auto;mso-list:l0 level1 lfo1'>Fimta23456 09:00:00 flor345<o:p></o:p></li><li class=MsoNormal style='mso-margin-top-alt:auto;mso-margin-bottom-alt:auto;mso-list:l0 level1 lfo1'>Fimta23456 09:00:00 flor345<o:p></o:p></li></ul><p class=MsoNormal><br>Thanks<o:p></o:p></p></div></body></html>
```

I would like to retrieve the original HTML that I put in the HTMLBody.

Comment: Where does this email go between `CreateHTMLMail` and when you are looking at it? There are steps there which are missing from your code above.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I create the mail with CreateHTMLMail, I sent it to myself, then I retrieve it with Get_OL. I would have liked to retrieve the same HTML as I initially created it.

Comment: The reason I ask is I tested nearly your exact code and am able to retrieve the HTML exactly as created. Are you on exchange? Or using something like gmail, etc?

Comment: I use Outlook. Can it have anything to do with RTF settings?

Answer (score 2):

2 ways:

**1)** parsing text - several things to do (*not recommended*: hard-coding)

All what you need is to [parse text](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd492012%28v=office.12%29.aspx#Outlook2007ProgrammingCh17_ParsingTextFromAMessageBody), but MSDN shows how to do it using **InStr** function. I would strongly suggest to use [RegEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms974570.aspx) to parse html text. Note: reference to *MS VBScript Regular Expressions x.x* is needed.

[Simple Regular Expression Tutorial for Excel VBA](http://www.macrostash.com/2011/10/08/simple-regular-expression-tutorial-for-excel-vba//)

**2)** using [UserProperites](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff866403.aspx) of MailItem object (*recommended*)

If MailItem doesn't contains your propert(y)ies, than there is nothing to do ;)

[How to: Add custom property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff862196.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, although I am not dealing with this problem anymore. Perhaps your answer can be helpful for other people nevertheless.